# Angularjs: Get document.querySelectorAll in ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to get the reference of my button in a ng-include! But it doesn't work. (I load my script.js in my index.html).

**Code in my script.js:**

```
buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#st-trigger-effects > button' ))
```

**Code in my ng-include controller:**

```
<div id="st-trigger-effects" class="column">
     <button data-effect="st-effect-3" class="pushmenutest">Push</button>
</div>
```

For your information, when i put my 'div' code directly in the index.html it Works! I don't know why, when i put my code in the ng-include view it doesn't work. Certainly, because the 'DOM' hasn't be loaded ?
I tried inserting script.js at the end of the file. But I have the same result.

I'm trying to use this library : http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/

Comment: Are you writing a test? or is it in your app?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kmwd4g8y/2/ - looks fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny, how can i affect the 'document.querySelectorAll' instance to the sidebar.js library ?

Answer (score 0):

If that line is by itself and not within say an angular context. It will run before the ng-include is done. Therefore the querySelector won't find the element.

I guesstimate this is the case because you say if you include the  in the .html directly it works.

Is there a reason why you need to get a hold of the button like that and can not use `ng-click`?

If you give us a bit more information we can help you further.